# ESLint configuration with Babel, Flow, React and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, flowtype, prettier

I'm developing a mobile application in React Native and I've been trying to configure ESLint properly for a while (including Babel, Flow and Prettier).

I get the following error in VSCode : `'module' should be listed in the project's dependencies. eslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)`.
This goes for all my modules and plugins such as react, react-native and others. I installed every package and the VSCode ESLint extension but ESLint still raises this error. Maybe I've duplicated some functionalities in the `extends` section too, I'm wondering if my configuration is good and if I can get rid of this error (everything else looks to work as expected).

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/babel",
    "prettier/react",
    "prettier/flowtype",
    "prettier/standard"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native",
    "flowtype",
    "standard",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "trailingComma": "es5",
        "singleQuote": true,
        "printWidth": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "PICSTART",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone XR\"",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "debugjs": "react-devtools",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@okgrow/react-native-copilot": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.3.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.78.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "testRegex": "./__tests__/[^setup].*.js$",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__tests__/setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error `eslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)` happens because you are importing a module that isn't in your `package.json.`

If everything is Ok, no errors while compiling, you could look at the [docs here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) and they explain how to disable this rule.

If `.eslintrc.json` and `package.json` aren't in the same folder, this may cause the error because eslint looks for `package.json` file but it can find it because it's in another folder.

**Edit:** Maybe you ar missing `"es6": true` in `"env"`

Try

```
"env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
},
```

Comment: What do you checked? What do you mean by it's to much for you?

Comment: I checked that my .eslintrc.json and package.json are both in the root folder. I also saw this rule but I don't want to disable the check for installed packages, this solution is more like a workaround. It should be able to work...

Comment: Please provide more information about your project, I can't know how to solve this only with that information.

Comment: import * as React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native'; These kind of imports raise the error. What else could I share?

Comment: in this part    `"ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }` try removing `"modules": true` and tell me if something changes

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything